# Analytic and smooth functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, taylor-expansion

In my work, I first make an assumption:

> Assume the function $f(x)$ is an analytic function of $x$.

Based on this assumption, I expand $f$ as Taylor series
$$
f(x)=f_0+f_1x+f_2x^2+f_3x^3+\dots
$$
Later, it is proven that the lower order terms $f_0=f_1=0$, and higher order terms $f_3=f_4=\dots=0$, i.e., $f(x)=f_2x^2$. As summary

> If the function $f(x)$ is an analytic function of $x$, then $f(x)=f_2x^2$.

My question:

> Does this mean the function $f(x)$ is of class $\mathcal C^2$ is enough? In other words, since the conclusion is $f(x)=f_2x^2$, then does the assumption automatically reduce to "the function $f(x)$ is of class $\mathcal C^2$"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We don't have enough information to answer. Is this coming from a DE?

Comment: @zhw . What is a DE?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so. Consider $f(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$. The function is $C^2$ (actually $C^\infty$), but obviously it is not analytic at $x = 0$, since $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for every $n$. Your proof relies on working with its Taylor expansion, so it is necessary to assume $f$ is analytic, otherwise you cannot conclude anything about the function itself.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer.